# Define Named Query in NHibernate Fluent Mapping without .hbm or xml files

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, named-query

Currently I am using NHibernate and Fluent mapping for as ORM.

I use named queries to call stored procedures. The named queries are saved in `.hbm` files.

e.g:

```
<hibernate-mapping default-cascade="none" 
   xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
   assembly="com.Entities" namespace="com.Entities" >  
   <sql-query name="QUERY_NAME" cacheable="false">
         <return class="FreeText" alias="results" >
            <return-property name="Id" column="FreeTextId"/>
            <return-property name="FreeTextValue" column="FreeText"/>
         </return>
         exec PROC_NAME :PARAM1, :PARAM2  
   </sql-query>    
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

I wanted to know if there is a way you can **define Named Queries in Mapping classes** so as to avoid using `.hbm` file altogether!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible yet, see https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Current-NHibernate-Features-Not-Supported-In-Fluent:

> Features not (currently) supported:
>
> - `<sql-insert>`
> - `<loader>`
> - `<database-object>`
> - `<sql-query>`
> - Changing Primary Key names (NHibernate limitation as well, currently)

Comment: :( Thanks for the link. I can never find a good complete resource on Fluent. Can you suggest any